# Relación de muchos a muchos en Laravel

Tags: sql, relaciones

Tengo serias dudas de como debo plantear en la Base de datos la relación de la tabla **usuarios** consigo misma, como veis se relaciona con dos tablas, **mensajes y valoración_usuario**, estas tablas reciben un campo rellenado a través de un formulario(**mensaje o valoración**) y las claves primaria de 2 de los usuarios de la tabla usuarios, cual es vuestro consejo?

Quizás una tabla pivote que pueda relacionarla consigo mismo? no lo tengo nada claro, Base de datos no es mi fuerte y estoy perdido, toda ayuda la agradeceré enormemente, **muchísimas gracias de antemano.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @BetaM como intentar de momento nada por que no se como debo hacerlo, he hecho antes relaciones de 1:n n:m en laravel, pero nunca una tabla que se relaciona con si misma, y no se ni por donde empezar.. el resto de las relaciones si, hablo de la que explico en el enunciado

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes tener en cuenta es hacer cumplir las restricciones de referencia para garantizar la integridad de los datos, considerando esto en tu caso necesitas crear en tu tabla usuario una llave foranea que en este caso seria la primary key de la tabla mensaje y otra llave foranea que seria la primary key de la tabla valoracion_usuario. De la misma manera en la tabla mensajes y la tabla valoracion_usuario debes crear una llave foranea que seria el campo primary key de tu tabla usuario de esta forma se interrelacionan las tablas y se garantiza la integridad de los datos.

Considera que en el caso que necesites relacionar 2 tablas de muchos a muchos lo mas usual es crear una tercera tabla constituida por 2 campos que serian la llave primaria de cada unas de las tablas que se relacionan de muchos a muchos.

te dejo una imagen de ejemplo y referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas Jorge, lo primero muchísimas gracias por perder tu tiempo, te lo agradezco mucho.
Creo que igual no me he explicado bien, como bien dices en una relacion n:m se crea 1tabla intermedia para la relación, como puedes ver en la imagen es lo que he hecho por ejemplo entre usuarios y viajes, mi duda viene cuando la tabla que relacionas es 2 veces la misma(usuarios) ya que necesito 2 veces el id de usuario, por ejemplo una para el que valora y otra para el usuario que está valorado.

Ahí está mi duda, que debo hacer cuando la relación de es entre usuario y usuario, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Es lo que te explique en la respuesta anterior, en la tabla usuario debes tener el idusuarios como clave primaria, el id_valoracion_usuarios como llave foranea y el id_mensaje como llave foranea, asi en la misma tabla usuario tendras todos los id relacionados. Trata de documentarte un poco acerca de llaves foraneas y lo veras claramente. Saludos!